# Distance between occurrences of a word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, python-re

I've got a text a file having some sentences. Suppose there are three sentences "Rahul backed from the market.","We are going to market", "All the shops are closed in the market."

Now I need to calculate the distance between the occurrences of the word "market".

Here it would be 5 and 8 because of the word "market" occurs after 5 words from the 1st occurrence of the word "market" and so on.

I'm using nltk word tokenizer to get the words. Actually I need to do it for most of the words present in the corpus.

Comment: Where is the code that is giving you trouble?  This appears to be straightforward string processing, not a NLP problem at all ... for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your list of words in order, you can enumerate them and make a lookup where the keys are the words and values are the lists of indices where the words are found:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

s = "Rahul backed from the market. We are going to market All the shops are closed in the market."

# using re for simplicity
words = re.findall(r'\w+', s)

positions = defaultdict(list)

for index, word in enumerate(words):
    positions[word].append(index)
```

`positions` will look like:

```
defaultdict(list,
        {'Rahul': [0],
         'backed': [1],
         'from': [2],
         'the': [3, 11, 16],
         'market': [4, 9, 17],
         'We': [5],
         'are': [6, 13],
         'going': [7],
         'to': [8],
         'All': [10],
         'shops': [12],
         'closed': [14],
         'in': [15]})
```

With that you can calculates the distances by zipping the lists and subtracting the indices:

```
distances = {}

for word, l in positions.items():
    distances[word] = [m - n for n, m in zip(l, l[1:])]
```

Now `distances` is a dictionary of of distances between the words. Items with only one word are empty lists since a distance doesn't make sense here:

```
{'Rahul': [],
 'backed': [],
 'from': [],
 'the': [8, 5],
 'market': [5, 8],
 'We': [],
 'are': [7],
 'going': [],
 'to': [],
 'All': [],
 'shops': [],
 'closed': [],
 'in': []}
```